# Annihilator of the unit closed ball in $c_0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X=\ell^\infty=(\ell^1)^*$ and $A=\{x\in X: x\in c_0, ||x||\leq 1\}$. Find $A_\perp$ and $(A_\perp)^\perp$, where $A_\perp$ is the pre-annihilator and $A^\perp$ is the annihilator.

My try is this: I noted that $A=B_{c_0}$, i.e., $A$ is the unit ball of $c_0$. Then
\begin{align*}
A_\perp=\{x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell_1:\sum_{n\geq 1} y_nx_n=0, \forall y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in B_{c_0} \}=\{0\}. 
\end{align*}
And for the other set, I think that $(A_\perp)^\perp=\ell^\infty$ .

Is this correct?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Your answer is correct.